# UITextFieldDelegate extension. Get content the user would see in UITextField. Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfielddelegate

I would like to pass the content of the text field into the `checkInput` method as the user sees the input in the text field. Currently, if a user deletes whitespace resulting in what should be a valid input, this is not working. Such an operation appears to send what is one input behind the visual representation of the UITextField content to `checkInput`.

```
    extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            var validInput = false
            if let textFieldText = textField.text {
                // TODO: handle removal of whitespace within text view
                let input = newInput(string, in: textFieldText, at: range.location)
                validInput = checkInput(newInput)
            }
            return !validInput
        }
    }
```

I have added a helper function, but this does not handle all cases (such as deleting whitespace)

```
func newInput(_ string: String, in stringText: String?, at rangeLocation: Int) -> String {
        let firstHalfString = (stringText as NSString?)?.substring(to: rangeLocation) ?? ""
        let secondHalfString = (stringText as NSString?)?.substring(from: rangeLocation) ?? ""
        return "\(firstHalfString)\(string)\(secondHalfString)"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have not understood what `shouldChangeCharactersIn` does. It is not "one input behind"; it is called before anything happens at all. That is what "should" means! This method is telling you what *might* happen and asking you what *should* happen.

That isn't what you want to know. You want to know what *did* happen. So you've implemented totally the wrong method.

What's the right method? A UITextField is a UIControl. Implement its `editingChanged` action-target pair to tell you whenever the text changes, and just read the text directly from the text field every time your action method is called.